# How can I configure QnAMaker tool to modify liststyle button in Skype?

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework, skype, azure-cognitive-services

I have made a bot using QnA Maker and Node JS which is running on Skype.
When the user inputs a word which has got multiple matches in FAQ link or document uploaded in QnA Maker, it shows button of choice using QnAMakerTool module from Node. My question is when the multiple matches has same initial words then because of the size of the choice button in Skype the half of the texts get hide. For example, I have three matches like

```
Whom should I contact for parking?
Whom should I contact for canteen?
Whom should I contact for Stationery?
```

It shows in Skype as

```
Whom should I contact for...
Whom should I contact for...
Whom should I contact for...
```

If the option text is too long then few parts get hidden. What can I do for this?
[image: This is the screenshot of the response]

Answer (score 3):

First of all, there is a limitation on the max characters in Skype, so that's something you will have to live with. However, you can implement some custom logic to change the text being shown.

That current logic that you are seeing is on the [QnAMakerTools](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/Node/src/QnAMakerTools.ts#L54) file.

[image]

The way to go here is probably providing your own QnAMakerTools implementation (it needs to follow [this interface](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/Node/src/QnAMakerTools.ts#L37)).

The [QnAMakerDialog](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/Node/src/QnAMakerDialog.ts#L47) receives an [IQnAMakerOptions](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/Node/src/QnAMakerRecognizer.ts#L54) parameter. One of the properties of that interface is `feedbackLib` which basically is the QnAMakerTools instance that the dialog will later use to disambiguate the question as you can see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/blob/master/Node/src/QnAMakerDialog.ts#L53).

Comment: Was this useful?